# URL encode a string in macOS terminal or shell script

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, urlencode

I need to URL encode a unix file path in macOS terminal or shell script
so that with this as input:

```
"/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Music/1-01 デ ジタルライフ.mp3"
```

I get this as output:

```
"file:///Volumes/Macintosh%20HD/Music/1-01%20%E3%83%86%E3%82%99%E3%82%B7%E3%82%99%E3%82%BF%E3%83%AB%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%95.mp3"
```

basically the same as dragging said file in a browser window and then copying its URL.
how can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you `use URI` in `perl`?

Comment: @Armali macOS provides `URI` but the command `perl -mURI::Encode -e 1` errputs `Can't locate URI/Encode.pm ...`

Comment: How about `perl -e 'use URI;print "file://".URI->new("/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Music/1-01 デ ジタルライフ.mp3");'`?

Comment: @Armali I knew there was a better way, that works perfectly. if you write that as an answer I'll select it as the correct one, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `use URI` in `perl`, whereby the automatic conversion of a URI object to string happens to do exactly what is wanted (except for the `file://`, which can simply be prepended):

```
perl -e 'use URI;print "file://".URI->new("/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Music/1-01 デ ジタルライフ.mp3");'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably better ways of doing it but I finally managed to do it this way:

```
printf %s "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Music/1-01 デ ジタルライフ.mp3" |
curl -Gso /dev/null -w %{url_effective} --data-urlencode @- "" | #urlencoding
cut -c3- | #cut the "/?" at the beginning
sed 's=%2F=\/=g' | #change "%2F" back to slash
sed 's=+=%20=g' | #replace "+" to urlencoded space (%20)
sed 's=^=file:\/\/=' #prepend "file://"
```

Result:

```
"file:///Volumes/Macintosh%20HD/Music/1-01%20%E3%83%86%E3%82%99%E3%82%B7%E3%82%99%E3%82%BF%E3%83%AB%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%95.mp3"
```